# Remove important styles in CSS

Tags: css

Im using google places api for a place autocomplete search - the user starts typing and results pop up.

I've styled the google container using !important to override the styles. So for my desktop css through media queries I have something like:

```
bottom: 100px !important;
top: auto !important;
```

Now on my mobile css, again through media queries, I need to move the position, I need the default styles back - the styles are controlled via google in the style tag on the element. But as I have used important i cannot remove them. I have tried:

```
bottom: auto !important;
```

Which fixes the bottom position, but how can I remove the top position so that it defaults to what is in the style tag on the element. I've tried:

```
top: auto !important;
top: inherit !important;
```

But with no luck.

Comment: Side note: That's why I avoid `!important` at all costs.

Comment: Using media query just try using like

@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
{
   top: auto !important;
}

Comment: Media queries might be useful here.

Comment: I would like to know how yo would do this without using important.

Comment: I am using media queries.

Comment: @SaiDeepak if you read the question I am using media queries already

Comment: bottom: auto won't override. try numeric

Comment: numeric does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by increasing specificity on your mobile css file and adding an !important value to this new value in the mobile stylesheet.

I'm not sure of your structure without seeing your html but if you can add an additional class or id to the parent container/element that is specific to mobile css and use that to target your mobile view

for example

```
#mymobile .classtooverride {newstyles !important;}
```

Comment: yeah, increasing specificity will do it, but this should be done if there is no other ways to do it.

Comment: I agree - this is one reason I intensely dislike !important and use it sparingly if at all.. but sometimes it is 'needed' unfortunately.

Comment: yeah, but what beginners do is adding !important if something style is not applying. they understand important as a one fit for all solution. it'll be a great pain when trying to modify the styles then they'll learn it eventually. Believe me I was there. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using that many `!important` 's is messy.

**A few suggestions:** (based on the little code your showing)

**2.** Don't override an `:auto` with an `:auto`. Try to override the styles with a number that give you similar look as `:auto`

**3.** Try removing all `!important` s and call the unique CSS within their perspective media query resolutions, properly. *eg.*

```
    @media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480){
         ... // Your unique styles to Mobile Here
    }
```

**4.** If all else fails; though, don't know why it would. You can [.toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with jQuery to attach a class within a condition. And `.removeClass` whenever you want. A simple fiddle of [.toggleClass (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/jdniki/UaT3P/) here.

*But you really should just be able to clean up your CSS and put everything in their specific media query defined resolutions.*